# RadHTMLChart renders Undefined YAxis after Subsequential Page Loads

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a Telerik RadHTMLChart that I render via a model, which is populated by a SQLCommand. Upon initial load, everything is great. The grid renders and it looks as nice as a Telerik control can look. HOWEVER, upon the second page load, say I click page 2 or 3, the grid gets populated at the top with a YAXIS that reads undefined. Then YAXIS data renders at the bottom. I have debugged this and cannot find anything online about this. Here's my code. Assume my SQL Query is awesome and works great, because trust me, it does.

```
 For Each recordAboutUserRoles In usageData
                If recordAboutUserRoles.usageCount <> 0 Then
                    Dim barz As New BarSeries
                    barz.Spacing = 0.4
                    barz.SeriesItems.Add(recordAboutUserRoles.usageCount, colorTheme.MainThemeColorLightened)
                    usageGraphByRole.PlotArea.Series.Add(barz)
                    i += 1
                End If
            Next
```

Assign data to the model here

```
Private Function AssignData(ByVal data As SqlCommand) As List(Of RolesByUsageModel)
    Dim result As SqlDataReader = data.ExecuteReader
    Dim rolesByUsageModelList As New List(Of RolesByUsageModel)

    While result.Read
        Dim rolesByUsageModel As New RolesByUsageModel
        rolesByUsageModel.usageCount = result.GetValue(0)
        rolesByUsageModel.roleName = result.GetValue(1)
        rolesByUsageModel.pageDefPageName = result.GetValue(2)
        rolesByUsageModel.pathUrl = result.GetValue(3)
        rolesByUsageModel.usageDetPageName = result.GetValue(4)
        rolesByUsageModelList.Add(rolesByUsageModel)
    End While

    Return rolesByUsageModelList

End Function
```

And here is my WebForm mark up. AxnData:AxnChart is proprietary branding. It is just a wrapper for the Telerik RadHtmlChart. Nothing is different but the control name.

```
<AxnData:AxnChart ID="usageGraphByRole" runat="server">
                                        <PlotArea>
                                            <Series>
                                                <telerik:BarSeries>

                                                </telerik:BarSeries>
                                            </Series>
                                        </PlotArea>
                                        <Legend>
                                            <Appearance Visible="false"></Appearance>
                                        </Legend>
                                        <ChartTitle Text="Usage By Role"></ChartTitle>
                                    </AxnData:AxnChart>
```

Here is what the chart looks like on initial load.

[image]

Chart after subsequential load.

[image]

When I inspect the element in DevTools, the "d" on the left of the chart, actually says Undefined. I have tried giving each AXIS Item a name, but that does not seem to work.

Anyone ever run into this?

Comment: Does the problem occur outside of the grid? If not, try disabling ViewState for the charts as it seems you creatre your charts in its ItemDataBound event, so something may be getting stored and thus unnecessary series and data being added the next time.

Comment: @rdmptn The solution was to add a SeriesItem in the For Each and instantiate the BarSeries outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it was all wrong. Assume usageGraph is being called on Page_Load. Then call the DataBound event. In the DataBound event declare the ChartSeries object outside of the loop and instantiate a new Chart Series Item inside the loop and add to the ChartSeries object.

The important part is to keep all of your data assignment in the DataBound event.

```
Private Sub usageGraph()

        usageGraphByRole.PlotArea.YAxis.LabelsAppearance.Visible = True
        usageGraphByRole.DataSource = AssignData()
        usageGraphByRole.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Private Sub usageGraphByRole_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles usageGraphByRole.DataBound
            usageGraphByRole.PlotArea.Series.Clear()

```
        Dim barz As New BarSeries()
        barz.Name = "Usage By Roles"
        'barz.LabelsAppearance.Visible = False
        barz.TooltipsAppearance.DataFormatString = "{0} Usage Count, {1}"

        For Each recordAboutUserRoles In AssignData()
            If recordAboutUserRoles.usageCount <> 0 Then
                Dim usageDataItem As New SeriesItem()

                usageDataItem.YValue = recordAboutUserRoles.usageCount

                barz.Items.Add(usageDataItem)

            End If
        Next

        usageGraphByRole.PlotArea.Series.Add(barz)

    End Sub
```